# Error while using Res.redirect method in node.js

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I'm trying to redirect my page after processing data from a form -
login information. But it gives an error, saying that res.redirect is
not a function !

### CODE:

```
app.use = ('/user',index);


function processFormFieldsIndividual(req, res) {
    var fields = [];
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.on('field', function (field, value) {
        //console.log(field);
        //console.log(value);
        fields[field] = value;
    });

    form.on('end', function () {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.redirect('/user');
        res.end(util.inspect({
            fields: fields
        }));
    });
    form.parse(req);
}
```

Comment: Where is this function `processFormFieldsIndividual ()` invoked? Please give us more information.

Comment: `app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];
    form.on('field', function(field, value) {
        fields.push([field, value]);
    })
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log(file.name);
        files.push([field, file]);
    })
    form.on('end', function() {
        console.log('done');
        res.redirect('/forms');
    });
    form.parse(req);
});` The above codes work well

Comment: @zangw I am still getting the same error stating that res.redirect() is not  a function

Comment: @zangw    ,The remaining necessary code ..............................................................................................                                                                       var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        displayForm(res);
    } else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        processAllFieldsOfTheForm(req, res);
    }

});